# jQuery pseudo select throws exception

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm pretty new to jQuery  .. I have a piece of code (which works) shown below  ..

```
var tablesToHide = $('.master-list-panel:visible');

    if (tablesToHide.length > 0)
        tablesToHide.hide();
```

but whilst debugging something else (which doesn't work) I notice that the above seems to be throwing an exception  ..

> Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document':
>   '.master-list-panel:visible' is not a valid     selector.

Can anyone tell me why ? .. As I say it works, but still logs an exception ..

Thanks

Comment: And can you show the HTML that correlates to this behaviour? Because the jQuery selector your wrote [seems to work, for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/12fdevrk/1/).

Comment: if you are using `ie<9` with `jQuery 2.xxx` lib then you should know this version does not support ie < 9 browsers.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.11 .. the html looks like   <div class="panel panel-primary master-list-panel" id="inventoryMasterListPanel"> .. I'm using Chrome .. As I say the code DOES work, it's just that when I ask the debugger to pause on Caught Expceptions  it stops with the indicated error .. I'm pretty new to this and i'm just trying to understand why ?

Comment: and I'm using Bootstrap 3 as well if that makes any difference ..

Comment: Can you put together a live ('[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)') demo of the code that reproduces your problem/triggers the debug messages?

Comment: [Not related] using just: `if (tablesToHide.length)` is enough..

Comment: also use `$('.master-list-panel').filter(':visible')` as mentioned in jquery docs..

Comment: Thanks to everyone  .. I'm from a mainframe programming background so its all a little new to me  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [not a bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13881#comment:1) according to jQuery:

> Resolution set to notabug
>
> Don't break on caught exceptions. We caught it because we expected it.

Lesson of the day: **don't break on caught exceptions :)**. I turn that on sometimes in Visual Studio for C# development and the number of thrown caught exceptions in framework DLLs is *frightening*.